# sql query .. confused

Tags: sql

I am a newbie and i am not sure how to go about this .. can anybody help me ?

Given the following tables ...

**DEPARTMENT**

```
DEPT_ID     NAME 
1   HR 
2   Technical 
3   Marketing 
4   Sales
```

**EMPLOYEE**

```
ID  NAME    DEPT_ID     SALARY  MANAGER_ID 
1   Alex    2   2000    
2   Sally   1   2000    
3   Amit    2   1500    1 
4   Jason   1   1500    1 
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

Using the `DEPARTMENT` and `EMPLOYEE` tables from earlier, write a SQL query to print the number of employees working in each department. The output should look something like this:

```
NAME    COUNT 
HR  2 
Technical   2 
Marketing   0 
Sales   0
```

Please note that not all departments have been staffed yet, so some departments may not have any employees. We still want these departments to appear in the results, with a zero count.

Using the `EMPLOYEE` table from earlier, write a SQL query to print out the number of employees working under each manager. The output should look something like this:

```
NAME    COUNT 
Alex    2 
Sally   0
```

Comment: Is this homework? Have you consulted a book?

Comment: please give me a direction .. i am not looking for the complete answer ..

Comment: start with SQL - that means here: use a SELECT statement.  Tell where the data comes FROM under what JOIN conditions..

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927772/create-a-query-to-select-two-columns-company-no-of-films-from-the-database/9930249#9930249) could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables, group by department, and take the count of rows per department.
[Try This Link](http://www.google.com/?q=sql%20join%20group%20count)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the first part of the problem:

```
select d.NAME, count(e.NAME)
from EMPLOYEE as e
right join DEPARTMENT as d
on e.DEPT_ID = d.DEPT_ID
group by d.DEPT_ID
```

Solution to the second part of the problem (I'm not sure whether this one is correct or not):

```
select NAME, count(NAME)
from EMPLOYEE 
group by MANAGER_ID
```

Please check the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e802/13

Comment: The second one is definitely not correct - the table would need to be self-joined (note that the results require the _manager's_ name to be printed.   For the first one, most people will have an easier time putting `Department` in the `FROM` clause, and `LEFT JOIN`ing to `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you :

a)

```
 select d.Name as DepartmentName, count(e.id) as EmployeeCount from employee as e, department as d where e.DEPT_ID = d.DEPT_ID group by d.Name;
```

b)

```
select a.name as Manager_Name,Count(a.name) as EmployeeCount from employee a, employee b where a.id=b.MANAGER_ID  group by a.name;
```